# clearmake doesn't like my MAKEFLAGS=j12 values

Tags: gnu-make, clearcase, clearmake

I use both GNU Make and - woe is me - ClearCase' clearmake.

Now, GNU make respect a flag named `MAKEFLAGS`, which for me is set to `j20` on this multi-core machine I'm on. Unfortunately, clearmake also recognizes this option, yet doesn't except this value. It tells me:

```
clearmake: Error: Bad option (j)
clearmake: Error: Bad option (2)
clearmake: Error: Bad option (0)
```

Questions:

1. Why is this happening? Should ClearMake accommodate GNU Make's usage?
2. How can I get around it, other then turning the flag off an on repeatedly?

Answer (score 1):

It's been 15 years or so since I used clearmake, but assuming it doesn't support the [GNU make-specific `GNUMAKEFLAGS` variable](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Options_002fRecursion.html) you can use:

```
export GNUMAKEFLAGS=-j20
```

and leave `MAKEFLAGS` unset.

Comment: That's interesting... will definitely give it a try.

Comment: This only works for GNU Make 4.0 and higher; I'm on a system with v3.81. But +1.

Comment: GNU make 4.0 was released almost 7 years ago.  GNU make 3.81 was released over 14 years ago.  It's about time to upgrade your tools.

Answer (score 0):

The "[BUILDING SOFTWARE WITH CLEARCASE](ftp://ftp.software.ibm.com/software/rational/docs/documentation/manuals/cc42unix/cc_qkref.pdf)" clearly states in its T"unsupported Gnu make features" that this option is indeed not supported.

```
–j [JOBS]
--jobs=[JOBS]
```

Maybe a  `clearmake -C -J` can help (for testing):  there should then be no limit to the number of parallel builds.

Comment: I don't mind that this is unsupported, I just want clearmake to ignore it rather than complain...

Comment: @einpoklum You would need to specify a dedicated MAKEFLAGS in a dedicated build script for that.

Answer (score 0):

Are you calling GNU make from a clearmake build script? Or are you trying to create a single makefile that will support both build tools? I think the GNUMAKEFLAGS EV is safer for GNU make specific values. I would also use

- CCASE_MAKEFLAGS for any makeflags that are specific to clearmake.
- CCASE_CONC to set the concurrency value. While clearmake no longer passes the -J in MAKEFLAGS, it used to, and if you're using an older clearmake (somewhere in the 7's as I recall), you could upset "child" GNU make sessions since they like -J about as much as clearmake likes -j.

Finally, check the env_ccase man page for the behavior mentioned in CCASE_MAKEFLAGS_V6_OBSOLETE. If you pass MAKEFLAGS explicitly in the build script like

```
$(MAKE) $(MAKEFLAGS) TARGET=x
```

And had started clearmake like this:

```
clearmake -C gnu TARGET=Y
```

You'll actually get both TARGET macro definitions in the command line. Setting the mentioned EV (at all) avoids the "pass defined macros in MAKEFLAGS" behavior. The switch exists because some people have makefiles that DEPEND on this behavior, while others have ones BROKEN BY this behavior...

Assuming for the sake of argument that your company has a support agreement with either IBM or HCL, this is a good time to use your support channels to bring up clearmake concerns.

Comment: GNUMAKEFLAGS is only usable with GNU Make 4.0 and later.